# Script run from crontab leaves an empty file

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, cron

I've tried to run a script from crontab on my Linux system which is leaving an empty file. When I run the script logged on the terminal, it works fine.

Cron line:

```
@reboot sleep 1m; /bin/bash /root/start_reader_services
```

The script "start_reader_services" calls a Python script as below:

```
/root/java/tag_output >> $TAGS_PATH/tags_$DATE_FILE.log
```

tag_output basically prints out a series of IDs. The same mechanics used to work when I was sending the stdout to my serial port (tag_output > /dev/ttyO0), but now, writing it to the file from cron, the file is created, but is empty.

As I mentioned, running start_reader_services or any piece of that on command line, it works as expected.

Have done:
 - Set bash as cron shell
 - Set java environments on cron

As requested:

```
ls -l /root/java/tag_output
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1981 Aug  6 12:06 /root/java/tag_output
```

First line of tag output:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Any help?

Comment: Is `tag_output` a Python script or Java program? At any rate, you probably don't need the [python] tag, since you're not asking about Python, as all the code you've posted is shell/crontab.

Comment: This might help..http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52330/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-from-within-cron

Comment: Add first line of /root/java/tag_output and output of `ls -l /root/java/tag_output` to your question.

Comment: tag_output is actually a Python script I wrote which does some stuff and calls a java app supplied by the HW vendor. It basically prints out the tags read back from the vendor app.

Comment: Added your suggestions to my question, thanks

Comment: So the Java app is actually doing the printing that you're trying to capture or are you capturing its output in `tag_output` and doing something with it and then printing what you want to capture?

Comment: Java prints, then I capture in tag_output (Python), do some parsing, processing and then print it out.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that `tag_output` is writing to *stderr* instead of *stdout*? Try redirecting *stderr* too:

```
/root/java/tag_output >> $TAGS_PATH/tags_$DATE_FILE.log 2>&1
```

As an aside, you might also want to quote and use braces with the shell variable expansion; that makes it easier to read and probably a little safer:

```
/root/java/tag_output >> "${TAGS_PATH}/tags_${DATE_FILE}.log" 2>&1
```

Comment: I don't think tag_output is writing to stderr since it usess "print" in Python, which writes to stdout as far as I know. Will try that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After initialising and updating the crontab using crontab python and before issuing

`cron.write(), give the command, 
cron.__reduce__()[2]['lines'] = filter(None, 
cron.__reduce__()[2]['lines'])`

Doing this will remove the empty lines being printed in Linux crontab.